# Writing the introduction section of an academic journal

Tags: journals, paper-submission, introduction

I have a question about writing the introduction section of an academic journal.

In particular, is it appropriate to include the potential impact of the research being proposed in the introduction section? For example, lines that begin with the following:

'This research offers a promising avenue for advancing our understanding of ...'

Are they supposed to be found in the introduction? Or is this kind of writing appropriate in some other section, if so, what section could it be?

Comment: Are you writing an article in an academic journal? or are you preparing the preface to a special issue of an academic journal? please be clearer

Comment: What do the journal guidelines say? Structure of introductions are very field and journal dependent.

Comment: @EarlGrey This is for a normal issue academic journal, not a special issue.

Comment: Is it the introduction to the journal or the introduction *of a paper you are submitting* to the journal? sorry for asking again.

Answer (score 1):

You should often follow the norms of the field you publish in, so that your fellow readers can quickly extract information from your papers.

With that caveat aside, it is perfectly sensible to discuss the potential impact of your paper in the Introduction. I personally have a mental four-paragraph template for the Introduction that goes something like:

*Context*

> Adding numbers is fun, as established with the seminal result that 1+1=2 (von Count, 1982).

*Challenges*

> However, larger addition problems can be challenging, as seen in several recent unsuccessful attempts to add 1 to 2 (Ernie and Bert, 1984).

*Our Awesome Paper*

> In this work we offer a comprehensive derivation that 1+2=3, drawing from number theory, Diophantine arithmetic, and analytic continuation via deep neural networks.

*Future Work*

> We expect our methods may be of assistance in tackling the yet harder problem of adding 1 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I would say an introduction to most pieces of academic writing should highlight what's important about the piece as well as the topic and argument. If what's important about your writing is the impact it will have on future reasearch, it should definitely be in the introduction; if not, it doesn't need to be.